# Install packages onto USB

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Kali Linux. The SD card is only 8 GB, and the image for Kali for the Pi does not come with many packages. I do not have much space left on the SD card, so I would like to install additional packages (tools) on a USB drive I've attached to the Pi. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily.

On a *supported* os, noobs should just let you install most of the OS to a USB drive and its entirely painless.

Of course, there's a small irony in needing to hack a hacker distro into working, but there's a few options. I'm assuming Kali's deb based off memory, and this should work for any distro.

First and foremost *back up first*. Many of these commands and configurations need advanced skills to carry out, and if you mess up, your entire install is hosed. I tend to use [win32 disk imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) here.

Mount your USB drive in a *fixed* location, preferably by ID rather than device name.

Individual packages:
May need some finessing and adjustments to your environment

Pick a installation directory. Add this to your path, and optionally create an environmental variable for it called $HACKY_INSTALL_PATH or something memorable and unique like that

Work out package requirements with `apt-cache rdepends`. Download these packages with `apt-get download package`. Install these packages to `dpkg -i --force-not-root --root=$HACKY_INSTALL_PATH package.deb`

See this [answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/350/17681) and this on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627158/howto-list-all-dependencies-of-a-package-on-linux)
 for more information. This should be fairly painless.

An alternative is to do what noobs does - your /boot needs to remain on the SD card (least on the original raspi) but everything else can be moved. Copy everything else out to the USB drive (rsync would be my option here - and make sure whatever you use preserves permissions and attributes) and ch change the location of / in your fstab to match, and make sure /boot is the SD card. Alternately mount just the relevant mountpoints as needed- ([bind mounts seem like a handy thing here](https://serverfault.com/questions/613179/how-do-i-do-mount-bind-in-etc-fstab), though of course a proper knowledge of the linux file system hierachy is useful. This is *risky* and I suggest you read up and plan ahead first. And of course, backup.